# Editing a file using async threads in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, discord, file-writing, discord-jda

I'm a small java developer currently working on a discord bot that I made in Java. one of the features of my bot is to simply have a leveling system whenever anyone sends a message (and other conditions but this is irrelevant for the problem I'm encountering).

Whenever someone sends a message an event is fired and a thread is created to compute how much exp the user should gain. and eventually, the function to edit the storage file is called.

which works fine when called sparsely. but if two threads try to write on the file at once, the file usually gets deleted or truncated. either of these two cases being undesired behavior

I then tried to make a queuing system that worked for over 24h but still failed once so it is more stable in a way. I only know the basics of how threads work so I may've skipped over an important thing that causes the problem

the function looks like this

```
    Thread editingThread = null;
    public boolean editThreadStarted = false;
    HashMap<String, String> queue = new HashMap<>();


    public final boolean editParameter(String key, String value) {
        queue.put(key, value);

        if(!editThreadStarted) {
            editingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while(queue.keySet().size() > 0) {
                        String key = (String) queue.keySet().toArray()[0];
                        String value = queue.get(key);
                        
                        File inputFile = getFile();
                        File tempFile = new File(getFile().getName() + ".temp");
                        try {
                            tempFile.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            DemiConsole.error("Failed to create temp file");
                            handleTrace(e);
                            continue;
                        }
                        //System.out.println("tempFile.isFile = " + tempFile.isFile());
                        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)); BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))){
                            String currentLine;

                            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                                if(trimmedLine.startsWith(key)) {
                                    writer.write(key + ":" + value + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                    continue;
                                }
                                writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            }
                            writer.close(); 
                            reader.close(); 
                            inputFile.delete();
                            tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            DemiConsole.error("Caught an IO exception while attempting to edit parameter ("+key+") in file ("+getFile().getName()+"), returning false");
                            handleTrace(e);
                            continue;
                        }
                        queue.remove(key);
                    }
                    editThreadStarted = false;
                }

            });
            editThreadStarted = true;
            editingThread.start();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

getFile() returns the file the function is meant to write to

the file format is

memberid1:expamount

memberid2:expamount

memberid3:expamount

memberid4:expamount

the way the editing works is by creating a temporary file to which i will write all of the original file's data line by line, checking if the memberid matches with what i want to edit, if it does, then instead of writing the original file's line, i will write the new edited line with the new expamount instead, before continuing on with the rest of the lines. Once that is done, the original file is deleted and the temporary file is renamed to the original file, replacing it.

This function will always be called asynchronously so making the whole thing synchronous is not an option.

Thanks in advance

Edit(1) :

I've been suggested to use semaphores and after digging a little into it (i never heard of semaphores before) it seems to be a really good option and would remove the need for a queue, simply aquire in the beginning and release at the end, nothing more required!

Comment: Have you considered synchronization? a semaphore? any sequentialization mechanism at all?

Comment: How about using that queue you mentioned and just having one thread actually write to the file? Also, depending on the amount of users, you might want to think about keeping the entire file in memory (in some kind of structure) and write a new version periodically (after an update or a bunch of updates). Alternatively you might want to think about some kind of sharding and indexing to make finding the records that need to be updated faster thus reducing the burden of the writer thread.

Comment: For the queue system, it is actually the function i just posted, as for storing the whole thing in a hashMap seems to be the simplest solution, we have about 32k members and im not sure if it would be really efficient, i will try and implement it this way and come back if i encouter any other problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `semaphore`s as per [user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421)'s suggestions and it seems to work perfectly

I simply put delays between each line write to artificially make the task longer and make it easier to have multiple threads trying to write at once, and they all wait for their turns!

Thanks